# Scala/Idea/Android through sbt-android: can't find typed (TR) stuff

Tags: android, scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have:

- sbt 0.13.11.2
- scala 2.10.6
- Android SDK 24.4.1
- Idea 16.1.2
- sbt-android plugin 1.6.6
- Java 1.8

So, what I did was all the steps described [here](https://github.com/scala-android/sbt-android) and then I opened generated project with my Idea. (So all .sbt and .properties are what gen-android provides). Here's generated code of sample.scala:

```
class MainActivity extends Activity with TypedFindView {
lazy val textview = findView(TR.text)

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
override def onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle): Unit = {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
    textview.setText("Hello world, from scaladroid2")
}
}
```

Idea tells me that it can't resolve TypedFindView, TR and some other references which all seems to be part of the sbt-android plugin. So I basically can't compile it and can't run it.

How it looks in the editor, red symbols are what is unresolved:
[image: How it looks in the editor, red stuff is what is unresolved.]

1. Have someone met this before? Googling got me nowhere. Is there a known way to fix this?
2. Can I go on without this stuff?
3. Is there an another way to get Scala to work with Android that works right now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a side comment, I do not know what your goal is, but developing native app for android with Scala is not the best idea.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ , my goal was self education, but I really want to know why this is a bad idea. Could you please explain?

Comment: false, scala code since 2.8 continues to run without problem on android marshmallow and nougat

Comment: turns out I also broke intellij's sbt-structure in sbt-android 1.6.0  :-( https://github.com/JetBrains/sbt-structure/pull/41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. import your project from SBT in IntelliJ
2. only build using sbt

If you import and build your project, TR is resolved.

IntelliJ does not know how to build scala projects, (or complex projects in general) do not use intellij to build.